# How can I print out the string "/\" in java?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
String [][] array =   {  {"     /\     "}, 
                         {"    /  \    "},
                         {"   /    \   "}}
```

I would like to print it out, but when I compile it, then always comes the following error message:

```
illegal escape character
```

And the "/\" gets marked.
I know, that /\ is the symbol for escape, but how can I bypass this?

For help I would be very gratefull!

Comment: Check [`Java Escape Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: TL;DR: Change it to `\\\`

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.print("/"); //will out --> /
System.out.print("\\"); //will out --> \
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape it, like this:

```
\\
```

Comment: Thank you!I I knew it was something like this, but I did not come out.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!